# LDS data coming null for a specific profile for a lightning component, the profile has view/modify all permission

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, profile

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:lightningQuickAction" >
    <aura:attribute name="record" type="Object"/>
    <aura:attribute name="opportunityRecord" type="Object"/>
    <aura:handler name="render" value="{!this}" action="{!c.onRender}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="renderVal" type="boolean" default='true'/>
    <force:recordData aura:id="record"
                      recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                      fields="Name,
                              Account.Id,
                              ContractId" 
                      targetFields="{!v.opportunityRecord}"/>
</aura:component>
```

This is my lightning component, and I am trying to access the record in my controller

```
onRender : function(component, helper) {
var opp=component.get('v.opportunityRecord');
        console.log('opp: ' +  opp);
}
```

and its coming as null. It is working fine for the sys admin and few other profiles but for one profile it does not work. On clicking the button which calls the lightning component, the model opens and closes withing 2 seconds.
I have checked the profiles and it seems to have access to the objects and fields, what could be the reason for this issue?
I am not getting any error message either.

Comment: Is there any reason you are not using lightning:recordform as force:recorddata is depricated?

Comment: hi @sanketkumar I am new to lightning, have just worked on one component, that I created recently only using with force:recordData and it worked fine. This component was already there I am just trying to debug what is causing this to not work for only a specific profiles, as per my knowledge force:recordPreview is deprecated but not sure about force:recordData. please advise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolution: you need to have the field level visibility for the fields that are 
used in LC. 
[found this useful](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30240/how-do-modify-all-data-and-view-all-data-affect-field-level-security-setting?rq=1)