# Managed Package overriding Field level Security access

Tags: managed-package, field-level-security, read-only

I'm having this issue 
I have some custom fields imported from a managed package which I need to set to "Read only". 
I have set the FLS to read only on these fields for all users but when I navigate to the page the edit option is granted and modifications are changed! I even set it to read only in the page layout but it still editable 
Do anybody have an explication or can help please?

Comment: This is likely the "Edit Read Only Fields" setting in your permissions for your user. See [this Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30240/how-do-modify-all-data-and-view-all-data-affect-field-level-security-setting) and [this knowledge article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000335725&type=1&mode=1).

Comment: System Admin always gets it

Answer (score 0):

Finally the user I've been login with had the 'Edit Read-Only Fields' permission via his profile, so he could edit no matter what, I only had to uncheck the permission.
Thank you !
[image: Edit Read-Only Fields permission]